# How can I draw a donut chart based on the number of specific fields on a form?

Tags: views, 7, forms, charts

Is there a module that can count results in a form, and then draw a donut chart like the following picture?

[image]

Note that I'm actually using content types and the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to create such forms. So I'm not using the commonly known [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module to create them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to create such charts (which are called **Donut Charts**) similar to the [sample in the Interactive Google Charts gallery](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#donut) (move your mouse pointer over any of the slices in that sample to see the special effects it comes with also). Such Donut chart is actually a [Pie chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#3D) with a hole in the center, which can be created with the `pieHole` option.

Below are some more details to get you going ...

**Option 1** (without using WebForm):

Use the [Comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) for potential alternatives to consider.

Some of the modules mentioned there:

- [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), which can be used to [Create charts using Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313837) ... as in these [Charts previews](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426177) and/or its [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/charts/examples/views). The D7 version of it comes with a choice between 2 [supported charting libraries](https://www.drupal.org/node/461914) to select from.
- [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart), which can be used to [Create charts using Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2433497) ... as in these [Chart previews](https://www.drupal.org/node/2431301). It requires the (deprecated) [Google Image Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/), and is expected to be upgraded in the near future to use another charting engine. Charting engines being considered are either of these JS libraries:

  - The [JIT](http://thejit.org/) (Javascript InfoVis Toolkit).
  - The [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) library.

**Option 2** (Using WebForm):

There are actually 2 alternatives to pick from:

- [Webform Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_charts) (used in about 400 sites), to display Webform results in a graphical manner using a charting library.
- [Webform Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_chart) (used in about 220 sites), which integrates with the "Analysis" tab of a Webform (created with the Webform module) to provide charts for each individual component's analytical data.

The Drupal 7 version of both modules, use the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module to actually create the charts (module dependency).

**Remarks**

The **license** that comes with the charting library (engine) that is used in the selected Charting module, should be considered also. Some of the typical items to consider are:

- Possible privacy concerns.
- Flash based libraries (as they were also used in the D6 version of Charts) should be avoided if charts are to be displayed on mobile devices.
- Google libraries require a working internet connection (not always available in local DEV environments ...).
- Not all libraries are free of charge (some come with commercial licenses).

Disclosure: I'm a (co-) maintainer of [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) and [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart), and the author of that Comparison.

Comment: I'm not using webform , I'm using content type and views to create forms ..  can I still use those methods ..

Comment: Anyone know what these charts are called? At the moment the question doesn't have the most useful content, but if we can update it to include that information it suddenly becomes very searchable

Comment: @Clive : Seems like a "Donut" chart, or possibly a "Pie chart" variation.

Comment: "Bon appetit" to anybody "digesting" that flavor of charts!

Comment: Thank you so much Mr @Pierre.Vriens for the valuable information. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you Rawan. Glad to read you seemed to like my answer (and that you also arked it as "accepted"). Charting in Drupal is really fun, can you tell from that "comparison" I mentioned? Also: no need for the "Mr", you can just call me "Pierre", ok? PS: if you run in other questions when experimenting with these charting modules, and can find the answer in the existing docu, then do not hesitate to create new questions also. If you run into "bugs" of "feature requests", then make sure to create an issue in the issue queue of that module on D.O., ok?

Comment: Extra curiosity: your screenshot shows you're using "CA"-products (I'm familiar with some of their mainframe prods, like "Endevor"). Are you now trying to implement some similar features using "Drupal" ... Like I'm also doing for some other similar product?